# Show content of element with full width without overlapping following elements

Tags: html, css

- I have a parent element with a child element.
- I need the child element to take full width of screen.
- I can't give the child element `100vw` because child element start with parent element. And the parent starts in a changeable vertical position

My Html Look like this

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="other-content"><div>
```

Comment: Please put your code into your question, HTML as well as CSS.

Comment: Is there no other CSS. Where are those classes defined?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So you have a nested div which you want to have full screen width? I don't understand the issue about the changable position of the parent div you mention. 100vw is full width right? Do you want the child element not to take full width but any space still allowed by the parent?

Comment: no parent is a container div and it have 3 child with same styles in one row. and every child have some information i want to make it full width so the 3 child have a different position and i want to fix them without exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Flexbox layout to have the `.child` take up any available space.

```css
.parent{
  display: flex;
}
.child{
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.other-content{
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="other-content">
other content
<div>
```